# beautiful soup not working when i run it for the first time

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 28, in <module>
    import cchardet as chardet_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cchardet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 33, in <module>
    import chardet as chardet_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/emwod/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/scrape.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bs4 as bs
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .builder import (
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 19, in <module>
    from bs4.formatter import (
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\formatter.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 37, in <module>
    import charset_normalizer as chardet_module
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

=== RESTART: C:/Users/emwod/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/scrape.py ==
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 28, in <module>
    import cchardet as chardet_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cchardet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 33, in <module>
    import chardet as chardet_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/emwod/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/scrape.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .builder import (
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 19, in <module>
    from bs4.formatter import (
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\formatter.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
  File "C:\Users\emwod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 37, in <module>
    import charset_normalizer as chardet_module
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I was trying to start `bs4` but this happend

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cchardet'

Seems not to be a strict `BeautifulSoup` topic - A module is missing, so you should install it or put it in path if you like to use it:

```
pip install cchardet
```

*Not sure if you need `cchardet` for your task.

Comment: this happend what should i do
  Running setup.py install for cchardet ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

   Running setup.py install for cchardet did not run successfully.
   exit code: 1

      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure